# Why does a process only satisfy the Markov property if and only if the random times are exponentially distributed?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, markov-chains

Given, for example, a birth death process with a set of jump times. These jump times have to be exponentially distributed in order for this process to satisfy the Markov property. Why is this? Why does it have to be an exponential distribution? I know that events occuring at random times are best described using an exponential distribution - but I do not see why this distribution is required.

[image: excerpt from script]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't . See [Renewal Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory). If you are talking about the *time* of the next event $T_{N+1}$ given the time of the last event $T_N$, then the *Markov Property* is that $P(T_{N+1}|T_N,T_{N-1}...)=P(T_{N+1}|T_{N})$. Nothing precludes the interarrival times from being any distribution, provided that inter-arriveal times are iid.

Note also that the [markov property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_process) applies to a much broader class of stochastic models than just the Poisson process.

Comment: Hm interesting, I updated my question with an excerpt from the script. Is it wrong or should I have mentioned the assumption of independence? The "process" mentioned is a birth death process.

Comment: @Dänu Sounds like they want the chain to be Markov wrt the calculation $P(T_{N+1}=t+s)=f(S,s)$ so that the probability the state will be in the next state at time $t+s$ depends only on the present state (S), not on the the time since the last transition.

Comment: @Dänu the answer is that yes, the statement in your book is correct, provided they mean markovian wrt current state and time increment.

Comment: Ok, that helps, thanks!